# make all possible pairs from different list in python

Tags: python, list, combinations

I used this way to make all combinations:

```
import itertools

lst = [[1, 2, 3], [1,2,2,4]]
combs = []

for i in xrange(1, len(lst)+1):
    combs.append(i)
    els = [list(x) for x in itertools.combinations(lst, i)]
    combs.append(els)
```

But what I want is that each list includes every possible combinations of elements inside. With the solution above, each element pairs are scattered. How can I solve it?

Comment: give sample input output so that we can understand your need!

Comment: It is not clear what you want. Give an example of desired output.

Comment: Can you share your result and desired output?

Comment: My desired output is like that,[[(1,2),(1,3),(1,2,3)],[(1,2),(1,4),(2,2),(2,4)]]

Comment: what does pair mean? is (1,2,3) a pair of numbers?

Comment: @WasiAhmad Thanks for remind. I was misundertood by my people. You are right, thanks so much!

Comment: @LanceChuang best way to thank is through accepting my answer.

Comment: error message:object of type 'itertools.chain' has no len()

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
import itertools

lst = [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 2, 4]
combs = []

for i in range(len(lst)):
    els = [list(x) for x in itertools.combinations(lst[i], 2)]
    combs.append(els)

print(combs)
```

Output

```
[[[1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 3]], [[1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 4], [2, 2], [2, 4], [2, 4]]]
```

Since you said, you want - `each element in its own list make pairs and put back in that list`, so i am assuming that `[1, 2, 3]` should be converted to `[[1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 3]]`. The above example does the same thing!

---

**Update**

If you want to generate all possible combinations (of length greater than 1) from those lists, then you can do something like this.

```
import itertools

lst = [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 2, 4]
combs = []

for i in range(len(lst)):
    temp_list = []
    for j in range(len(lst[i])+1):
        if j < 2: # skipping zero and one length combinations
            continue
        els = [x for x in itertools.combinations(lst[i], j)]
        temp_list.extend(els)

    # remove duplicate combinations
    new_list = []
    [new_list.append(i) for i in temp_list if not new_list.count(i)]
    combs.append(new_list)

print(combs)
```

Output

```
[[(1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3), (1, 2, 3)], [(1, 2), (1, 4), (2, 2), (2, 4), 
  (1, 2, 2), (1, 2, 4), (2, 2, 4), (1, 2, 2, 4)]]
```

Comment: But I don't want to assign number of pairs.
I would like all possibilities in those combinations.